# illegal symbol `forall` in type, RankNTypes

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, cabal

I am trying to build [Future.hs](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts/Future.hs) from plutus-use-case from scratch. I take two files from [plutus-starter](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-starter): `cabal.project` as is, and `plutus-starter.cabal` that I have to edit according to the imports in Future.hs. I get however these errors when I run `cabal build`:

```
src/Plutus/Contracts/Future.hs:574:8: error:
    Illegal symbol `forall' in type
    Perhaps you intended to use RankNTypes or a similar language
    extension to enable explicit-forall syntax: forall <tvs>. <type>
```

I also had to add several other modules e.g. Plutus.Contracts.Currency and for every .hs file with `forall`, do I have to add `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `LANGUAGE` pragmas are required, best practice is probably following Plutus code examples and having separate pragmas per-file as needed.

It is also possible to allow some extensions globally via `.cabal` file by using `default-extensions`, e.g.:

```
library
 default-extensions:
   DataKinds
   RankNTypes
```

but this should be done with care and can bite later as some extensions are not compatible.

Also instead of adding files locally, try adding `plutus-use-cases` to the list of your dependencies, then you can `import Plutus.Contracts.Currency`.

Comment: I never thought of adding `plutus-use-cases` thats helpful!